# How to pick up data from one field based on the condition of another field

Tags: java, if-statement, stream

How to pick up data from one field based on the condition of another field?

As shown below, I want to populate the class 'simulation' with the data from the class 'salary', the condition is like:

1. simulation.id = salary.id;
2. Some id has simulatedSalary, some id has notsimulatedSalary, some id has both of simulated and notsimulated Salary;
3. if(salary.simulated == true) then simulation.simulatedSalary = salary.salary, else simulation.simulatedSalary == 0;
4. if(salary.simulated == false) then simulation.notsimulatedSalary = salary.salary, else simulation.notsimulatedSalary == 0;
5. simulation.totalSalary = sum(simulation.simulatedSalary + simulation.notsimulatedSalary).

How to implement the above condition?

to populate `List<simulation> simulationList` from `List<salary> salaryList`:

```
public class salary {
private Integer id;
private Boolean simulated;
private Double salary;
```

}

```
public class simulation {
private Integer id;
private Double simulatedSalary;
private Double notsimulatedSalary;
private Double totalSalary;
```

}

Comment: this code makes no sense. I think you need to revisit a basic java tutorial.

Comment: hi @QSY please follow the naming convention of java using this website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to implement the above code you should use inheritance also you should use `protected` data fields and not private for both of your class

sample usage of inheritances: in this code, your parent class is `Salary` and your child class is `Simulation` then you must set your data fields to be `protected` instead of `private` so that the child class can use its parent class variable directly

in inheritance child class can use all the methods and fields that are `public` or `protected` by the parent class

```
 public class Salary
    {
       protected Integer id;
       protected Boolean simulated;
       protected Double salary;

    }

public class Simulation extends Salary
{
 //you do not need Integer id here
 private Double simulatedSalary;
 private Double notsimulatedSalary;
 private Double totalSalary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I follow your suggestion to do the logic like:      public void setSimSalary(Double simSalary) {
        this.simSalary = super.getSimulated().equals("Y") ? this.simSalary = super.getSalary() : 0;
    }

Comment: @QSY using `protected` variable means when you create an object of Salary that object cannot directly access its variable, only child class of Salary can access a variable of Salary directly

Comment: @QSY note that multiple inheritance is not allowed in java but you can create an `interface` to have 2 parents class or more

Comment: @QSY multiple inheritance is not allowed because when you extend it to have 2 parent class you don't know which `super` is which, so java don't allow  multiple inheritance only `interface`

Comment: @QSY please note that you can create a multiple generations of inheritance for example `Animal` is the superclass you can create `Dog extends Animals` then you can create `SonDog extends Dog` then you can create `GrandSonDog extends SonDog` then `UltimateSuperGrandSonDog extends GrandSonDog` then `UltimateToTheMaxOfTheUltimatesGrandSonDog extends UltimateSuperGrandSonDog` also `TheFinalBossGrandSon extends UltimateToTheMaxOfTheUltimatesGrandSonDog`